# Http Client with Source.tick

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to connect http client to a http service exposed by server, the source should send request every 1 second for that I have crated following partial graphs:

```
def httpSourceGraph() = {
  Source.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
    val sourceOutLet = builder.add(Source.tick(FiniteDuration(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS), FiniteDuration(1,
      TimeUnit.SECONDS),
      HttpRequest(uri ="/test", method = HttpMethods.GET))).out
    // expose outlet
    SourceShape(sourceOutLet)
  })
}

def httpConnFlow() = {
  Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>

    val httpSourceFlow = builder.add(Http(system).outgoingConnection(host = "localhost", port = 8080))

    FlowShape(httpSourceFlow.in, httpSourceFlow.out)
  })
}
```

the graph is composed as

```
val response= httpSourceGraph.via(httpConnFlow()).runForeach(println)
```

if the http server (localhost:8080/test) is up and running, everything works fine, every 1 second I can see the response coming back from the server. I am not able to any response in case of  either server is down or it goes down later.

I think it should give me following error:

akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(localhost/127.0.0.1:8080,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed

This can tested with some wrong url as well. (domain name stackoverflow1.com and wrong url "/test")

Thanks for the help.

-Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can propose one way to get the behavior that you are seeking.  I think what's at the heart of your issue is that the `Flow` produced by `Http().outgoingConnection` will terminate when a failure is encountered.  Once that happens, there is no more downstream demand to pull the requests from the `Source` and the whole flow stops.  If you want something that will continue to emit elements downstream regardless of if the connection is lost then you might try and use a host connection pool instead of just a single connection.  The pool will be more resilient to failures with individual connections and it's also setup from the get go to send either a `Success` or `Failure` downstream.  A simplified version of your flow, using a host connection pool could be defined as follows:

```
 val source = 
   Source.tick(
     1 second, 
     5 second, 
     (HttpRequest(uri ="/", method = HttpMethods.GET), 1)
   )

 val connFlow = Http(system).
   newHostConnectionPool[Int](host = "www.aquto.com", port = 80)

 val sink = Sink.foreach[(util.Try[HttpResponse], Int)]{
   case (util.Success(r), _ ) => 
     r.entity.toStrict(10 seconds)
     println(s"Success: ${r.status}")

   case (util.Failure(ex), _) => 
     println(s"Failure: ${ex.getMessage}")
 }

source.via(connFlow).to(sink).run
```

I tested this out, unplugging my network connection in the middle of the test and this is what I see as output:

```
Success: 200 OK
Success: 200 OK
Failure: Tcp command [Connect(www.aquto.com/50.112.131.12:80,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed
Failure: Tcp command [Connect(www.aquto.com/50.112.131.12:80,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed
Failure: Tcp command [Connect(www.aquto.com/50.112.131.12:80,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed
Success: 200 OK
Success: 200 OK
```

Comment: why it is returning tuple (response,int). I would prefer only response.

Comment: The pools are setup to allow you to push multiple concurrent requests down into them at once.  When you do this, there is no order guarantee on the responses that come out (i.e. order in does not necessarily equal order out).  That's what that second slot on the tuple is for, but for your case, you aren't passing in multiple requests at once and are only doing one, so that's why that id is being set to 1 on the request side and completely ignored on the response handling.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. how It is different than using Http(system).outgoingConnection(host = "localhost", port = 8080)

Comment: You should read the docs as they will provide a wealth more of knowledge than can be discussed in this space: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/http/client-side/index.html

Comment: Great... I am going through same. Thanks again